# Laravel Forge: Unable to create AWS EC2 instance in London Region

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, php5, amazon-vpc

When I try to create a server on Laravel Forge for AWS in the London region I get the following error message:

```
Whoops! There were some problems with your input.

    The server provider was unable to create your server. Either try contacting your server provider for more details or add a new server provider credential in your account profile.
```

I use to be able to create instances in the London region, I still have 3 of them running. I noted this issue last week, and gave it a couple of days thinking it was perhaps issues on Forge's end. I tried creating new credentials for Forge and I have the same issue using these new credentials.

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to launch a m5.4xlarge instance.

**UPDATE 2:** 
So after reading @ceejayoz's suggestion, I tried a m5.2xlarge instance and that worked. However, I need that m5.4xlarge instance, so I'll probably end up provisioning a load balancer as well, but that means 3 instances as opposed to one. I'm not going to mark this question as correct, since creating a m5.4xlarge instance in other regions works.

Comment: I suspect Forge is trying to create an instance type that's being deprecated, like the old `m1.small` instances were. Try a different instance type, or let us know which type you're trying to launch.

Comment: I'll update my post.

Answer (score 3):

In some regions / availability zones there is not enough capacity for the new M5 / C5 / T3 instances. If you can choose AZ (Availability Zone) in the Laravel Forge create dialog try a different AZ in your region - it may work.

If it still doesn't work raise a Support request -> Service limit increase for your desired instance type.

You can also try to spin up m5.4xlarge manually through the EC2 console to see if that works or if it fails as well. And if it fails you may get a better error message from the EC2 console than from Forge.

Hope that helps :)